# Monitoring user activity restricted to GUI apps

Tags: 22.04, scripts, google-chrome, software-recommendation, gui

I wish to monitor what all apps were opened on the PC at any time. I mostly use it for operating GUI apps like chrome, vlc media player, etc. Specifically, I would like to know which app I opened at what time and for how long it was used. This could help me trace where my time went by. There are a lot of apps on android that do this, but how do I achieve this in Ubuntu?
On researching internet a bit, including on ubuntu stack exchange, I couldn't find a satisfactory answer. Most command line options give current status/ history of terminal commands made by the user, or processes running in the system.

Is there a way to modify these commands (using options, etc) to make them behave like an app monitor for android, so that only GUI apps such as chrome, vlc media player, file manager, etc are shown instead of all processes? Or alternatively, is there a GUI app or terminal package that does this? I only wish to know what time went where, not as such 'lock' the app or restrict access to it.
Additionally if the command/ app could seperate tabs opened in chrome and monitor them as seperate activites that would be great.